# Displaying Esri Grid Format correctly in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, esri-grid-format

I think I've come across a Bug in ArcMap 10 in displaying rasters.  This particular model comes from the [USGS GAP Species dataset](http://www.gap.uidaho.edu/species_data.html) with metadata hosted [here.](https://s3.amazonaws.com/GapFTP/Nat_Species_Metadata/SpeciesModels.html)  **I'd like to know if anyone else has experienced this issue or if this is something I have to pursue with ESRI support.**

File type: ESRI GRID

The Value field in the model is limited to a domain containing 1, 2 or 3, which represents a seasonal distribution of the given species (see metadata below).

[image]

**When added to the map, I'm getting arbitrary values in this field.**  You'll notice that all raster cells are grey and seem to fall within the 1-3 value domain.

[image]

I've gone into the properties to change from 'Stretched' symbology to 'Unique Values' when I'm prompted to build raster attribute table (which fails).  The distributor of the dataset suggested to try the geoprocessing tool to build the attribute table, but it yeilds this error message.  I went into the source tab and confirmed that the raster *pixel type is signed integer* and the raster only contains *one band.*

[image]

Comment: I'm not clear what the question is, but if you think its a bug report it to your ESRI support folks.

Comment: I'm trying to understand if this is user error, or a bug.  Has anyone else experienced this type of behavior?

Comment: I downloaded the Baltimore Oriole distribution grid. It is displayed correctly in ArcMap 10.0 (SP 2) and even in the ancient ArcView 3.3--all 92029 rows and 118352 columns. Possibly there's a new bug in the latest version of ArcMap; there may be some corruption in your particular file; or conceivably some setting in your system is causing this misbehavior. Have you downloaded another grid as a double-check?  One more thought: are you performing on-the-fly reprojection?  Perhaps that is converting integer to floating values.

Comment: This has happened on all of the Raster datasets I've downloaded since getting my temp computer from IT.  ArcMap 10.0 SP4 Build 4000.

Comment: Roy, do you mean all raster datasets regardless of format, or *Grid* format rasters only? The ancient Grid format, with its implicit dependencies among child and sibling directories, is brittle and unstable: corruption in one INFO directory can affect the processing of many Grid files (sometimes system wide, in my experience). When you extract the downloaded grid dataset, do you do so within a *new*, *empty* folder created for the purpose?  One whose full path complies with 8.3 file naming conventions? This is your best protection against such problems.

Comment: I'll admit I've never used 8.3 so I'm not familiar with the naming conventions. I got a similar result from .bil files (bioclim dataset).  GRID format was my second choice to an .img. For whatever reason, the 300MB .img zip file contained what my Win7 machine interpreted as a 6 Petabyte .ige file (the file that supposedly stores image data in large .img files) so I was unable to extract it

Comment: 8.3, LOL! The naming conventions date to the 70's and 80's, decades before ArcGIS was built. (ArcGIS appears to incorporate lots of legacy code in its raster-handling portion.) At any rate, there are clues in your tale: the Grid format uses a run-length encoding to compress integer rasters, which is why a grid with 10^10 cells can be stored in less than a gigabyte on disk. The expansion to a 6 petabyte .ige file obviously is a bug somewhere: even at four bytes to a cell (uncompressed), that grid would have more than 10^15 cells.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What format is the raster in?  I am guessing ArcGrid because I didn't see any other download links on that web site.
First you are not crazy.  I have found that pretty much any thematic raster created outside of Arc is going to open in a greyscale format.  Then you will need to either calculate the attribute table or statistics.  So that part is pretty common, however having that step fails is odd.  If it is in the ArcGrid format...  I suggest converting it to another format, either tif or img.  You should be able to do this in arc with the Raster To Other Format tool in the Conversion Toolbox or with the Import tools in Erdas (if you have that).  If this fails as well...  I would try redownloading the data because something seems to be broken with the raster.

Comment: This is a GRID file, I believe it's also available for download as an .img, but it shows 6 petabytes when I try to unzip it for some reason.  I'm trying the file conversion now, we'll see how that goes.

Comment: Converting to either Imagine image (.img) or Tag Image File Format (.tiff) enabled the building of the attribute table. -- THANKS